# How can I check if a record exist in Oracle database with Java?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I am trying to check if a record exist in a database and I am not sure how  to execute this query, It gives error with executeQuery(checkSql). Can you help me, please?

```
public void addScore(int score, String name)
{
    try {
        con = mgr.getConnection();

        String checkSql = "if EXISTS (select * from HIGHSCORES where name = '"+name+"')";

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        //ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(checkSql);



        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mgr.closeConnection(con);
}
```

Comment: What error does it give?  In general, this helps you get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String checkSql = "select count(*) from HIGHSCORES where name = '"+name+"'";

Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(checkSql);
result.next();
if ( result.getInt(1) == 0) {
  System.out.println("doesn't exist");
} else {
  System.out.println("exists");
}
```

To make this better, you'd switch to a PreparedStatement which prevents SQL injection

Comment: I tried this, but now it gives "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error.

Comment: Try again.  I missed removing the trailing paren.

Comment: If you add a `where rownum < 2` to the query it could be a lot more efficient. You then don't scan the full table but only one record. This code is also wide open to SQL injection from what I can see...

Comment: Ideally it would scan a full index not a full table, but your point still applies. However rownum doesn't run on all databases as far as I know.  (I remember limit and top.)  I try not to use db specific code unless I have to.  We don't know there is a performance problem here.  There probably isn't since it is a learning example.  Also, I already mentioned SQL Injection in my answer.  I didn't fix it so the mapping between "before" and "after" code would be clearer.

Comment: _"To make this better, you'd switch to a PreparedStatement which prevents SQL injection"_ - yes, that's true, why do you show a bad example - which should be avoided - then? :)

Comment: @Sk8erPeter: so the original poster can more easily compare the original/revised version

Answer (score 3):

Strangely, for many db's exists can only be used as a conditional , not as a result itself. As an example, the following is valid

```
select * from some_table where exists (select * from HIGHSCORES where name = '"+name+"')
```

But this is invalid for many systems.

```
exists (select * from HIGHSCORES where name = '"+name+"')
```

If this happens though you can just get whether a record exists with the following

```
select count(*) from HIGHSCORES where name='"+name+"' limit 1
```

this will get you the count, and will stop after finding at least one record, a small optimization.

Comment: You should definitely use PreparedStatement instead of this solution and avoid concatenating the query string.

Comment: This answer was attempting to be nearly all SQL syntax and to use the op's own code for clarity. If you are using Java then yes PreparedStatements are better but that was not the question asked.

Comment: The question was how to do the whole thing in JDBC - which of course includes how to write an appropriate query for the task. So yes, you should use PreparedStatement. AND yes, you should use prepared statements everywhere if it's possible (in every other languages+libraries too). So I think everyone should avoid showing bad examples. :)

Comment: The queries I'm presenting work and are clear SQL examples that show how to approach the problem in a language independent manner(more or less, easily adaptable). You can clarify the answer with your comment to use a PreparedStatement when using specific languages if you would like, but it's not a bad example and is distinct from the accepted answer.